# Django makemigrations error: "__init__() got an unexpected keywork argument 'max_Length'

Tags: python, django, migration, django-errors, makemigrations

I am trying to make migrations to a new app 'users' and keep receiving the error:
"TypeError: Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_Length'"

I previously encountered this error when making migrations on my last app and was able to find the solution on a stackoverflow post which I can't seem to relocate.

I know that max_Length is valid because it worked last time but can't seem to remember what I did to make the migrations work.

[My settings.py files with the users app activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iYTk.jpg)

```
 > INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```

[My models.py in my users app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLz6k.jpg)

```
> from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User #/Django User Model 
import uuid 
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_Length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default="profiles/user-default.png")
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_instagram = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
                    primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out what I am missing but can't seem to get it.

- Python manage.py makemigrations worked last time with the projects app having the same 'max_Length' constraints.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not max_Length. It's max_length.

Comment: My texteditor automatically capitalizes the L and it worked for the last one despite getting the same error originally

Comment: Your text editor has no authority over the API.

Comment: @KlausD. understood that is my problem. Do you have any ideas on how I can remove the automatic formatting that VS code uses to make it max_Length. It isn't letting me do max_length when just typing the code. Automatically capitalizes that L.

Comment: @RohanBaddi had it right: max_length NOT max_Length. VS Code makes the capital and lowercase L look unreasonably similar - thanks guys!